# JavaScript calculator for adding discounts on some number of people

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am trying to learn JS and I am trying to make a simple calculator which will calculate price against number of people and will give discount on some amount of people. For instance, every 6th person is completely free.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMoqzo) is example what I did until now.

**HTML**

```
    <input type="number" id="int_no_of_people" value="" onchange="mycalculator()">
<input type="number" id="int_no_of_kids" value="" onchange="mycalculator()"> <br>
price <p id="price" > </p> <br>
dep <p  id="depozit" > </p> <br>
<br>
price <input type="text" id="var_cena" value=""><br>
dep <input type="text" id="var_dep" value=""><br>
```

**JS**

```
function mycalculator() {

  //var de=document.getElementById("de").innerHTML;
  //var de2=document.getElementById("de2").innerHTML;
  var a = 10; //<? echo $resultde1; ?>;

   var adultprice = 10; //adult price
  var kidprice = 5; //kid price
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("int_no_of_people").value, 10);// number of addults
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("int_no_of_kids").value, 10);// number of kids
  var s = 6; //every 6th get discount
  var aj = 2; //fixed Deposit amount adult
  var kj = 1; //fixed Deposit ammout kids
  var u = ""; //document.getElementById("var_jetski").value; // Discount coupon
  var pm = "-6oFf"; /*<? echo $kalk_row['code']?>*/ // discount coupon verification code 
  var pp = 6; // How much discount coupon worth
//  alert(a);

  s = s || 0;
  x = x || 0;
  y = y || 0;

  if (s > 0) {

    if (x + y >= s && x + y < (s * 2)) {

      var xx5 = a * x;
      var yy5 = c * y;
      var p5 = xx5 + yy5 - s;
      var d5 = (aj * x) + (kj * y) - aj;
      var k5 = p5.toFixed(2);
      var j5 = d5.toFixed(2);
      //document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = s;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = k5;
      document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = j5;
      //document.getElementById('dis2').style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById('var_cena').value = k5;
      document.getElementById('var_dep').value = j5;

      if (u == pm) {
        var nd5 = d5 - pp;
        var cp1 = nd5.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('var_dep').value = cp1;
        document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = cp1;
        document.getElementById("save").innerHTML = pp;
        document.getElementById('save1').style.display = "block";
      }
    } else if (x + y >= (s * 2) && x + y < (s * 3)) { //2

      var g1 = s * 2;
      var xx1 = a * x;
      var yy1 = c * y;
      var p1 = xx1 + yy1 - g1;
      var d1 = (aj * x) + (kj * y) - aj;
      var k1 = p1.toFixed(2);
      var j1 = d1.toFixed(2);
      //document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = g1;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = k1;
      document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = j1;
      //document.getElementById('dis2').style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById('var_cena').value = k1;
      document.getElementById('var_dep').value = j1;

      if (u == pm) {
        var nd1 = d1 - pp;
        var cp2 = nd1.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('var_dep').value = cp2;
        document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = cp2;
        document.getElementById("save").innerHTML = pp;
        document.getElementById('save1').style.display = "block";
      }

    } else if (x + y >= (s * 3) && x + y < (s * 4)) {

      var g2 = s * 3;
      var xx2 = a * x;
      var yy2 = c * y;
      var p2 = xx2 + yy2 - g2;
      var d2 = (aj * x) + (kj * y) - aj;
      var k2 = p2.toFixed(2);
      var j2 = d2.toFixed(2);
      //document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = g2;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = k2;
      document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = j2;
      // document.getElementById('dis2').style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById('var_cena').value = k2;
      document.getElementById('var_dep').value = j2;

      if (u == pm) {
        var nd2 = d2 - pp;
        var cp3 = nd2.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('var_dep').value = cp3;
        document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = cp3;
        document.getElementById("save").innerHTML = pp;
        document.getElementById('save1').style.display = "block";
      }

    } else if (x + y == (s * 4) && x + y < (s * 5)) {

      var g3 = s * 4;
      var xx3 = a * x;
      var yy3 = c * y;
      var p3 = xx3 + yy3 - g3;
      var d3 = (aj * x) + (kj * y) - aj;
      var k3 = p3.toFixed(2);
      var j3 = d3.toFixed(2);
      //document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = g3;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = k3;
      document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = j3;
      // document.getElementById('dis2').style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById('var_cena').value = k3;
      document.getElementById('var_dep').value = j3;
      /*if (u == pm) {
                     var nd3= d3-pp;
                     var cp4 = nd3.toFixed(2);
                        document.getElementById('var_dep').value = cp4;
                document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = cp4;  
                document.getElementById("save").innerHTML = pp;
                document.getElementById('save1').style.display = "block";
      }*/
    } else if (x + y >= (s * 5)) {

      var g4 = s * 5;
      var xx4 = a * x;
      var yy4 = c * y;
      var p4 = xx4 + yy4 - s;
      var d4 = (aj * x) + (kj * y) - aj;
      var k4 = p4.toFixed(2);
      var j4 = d4.toFixed(2);
      // document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = g4;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = k4;
      document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = j4;
      //document.getElementById('dis2').style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById('var_cena').value = k4;
      document.getElementById('var_dep').value = j4;

      if (u == pm) {
        var nd4 = d4 - pp;
        var cp5 = nd4.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('var_dep').value = cp4;
        document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = cp5;
        document.getElementById("save").innerHTML = pp;
        document.getElementById('save1').style.display = "block";
      }

    } else if (x + y < s) {

      var xx6 = a * x;
      var yy6 = c * y;
      var p6 = xx6 + yy6;
      var d6 = (aj * x) + (kj * y);
      var k6 = p6.toFixed(2);
      var j6 = d6.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = k6;
      document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = j6;
      //document.getElementById('dis2').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('var_cena').value = k6;
      document.getElementById('var_dep').value = j6;

      if (u == pm) {
        var nd6 = d6 - pp;
        var cp7 = nd6.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('var_dep').value = cp7;
        document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = cp7;
        document.getElementById("save").innerHTML = pp;
        document.getElementById('save1').style.display = "block";
      }
    }

  } else {
    var xx = a * x;
    var yy = c * y;
    var p = xx + yy;
    var d = (aj * x) + (kj * y);
    var k = p.toFixed(2);
    var j = d.toFixed(2);
    //document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = s;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = k;
    document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = j;

    document.getElementById('var_cena').value = k;
    document.getElementById('var_dep').value = j;

    if (u == pm) {
      var nd = d - pp;
      var cp = nd.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('var_dep').value = cp;
      document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = cp;
      document.getElementById("save").innerHTML = pp;
      document.getElementById('save1').style.display = "block";
    }

  }

}
```

Functionality is around 50% but the code looks ridiculous. I am wondering if it's possible to achieve this in a better way.

The biggest problem I get is following the number of people and, every time the number increases, comparing it with the number for the discount. As I started writing with `if`s, I saw that it's good until one point, such as handling no more than 50 people.
Here i tryed to escape all possible ifs and move over increment and basicly its working only one by one:( 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVOBVw

Comment: For your code to be reviewed, please refactor it with **significant variables**. We can understand what are `x` and `y`, but from there it quickly becomes like a puzzle! Anyway, using significant variables is one of the main best practices.

Comment: oks @ cFreed i will did that in next few sec

Comment: I have to agree that this code is _very_ hard to figure out. The only description we have is "for instance, every 6th person is free", but in that case it'd just be `total = (people - Math.floor(people/6)) * price`, and done. Obviously there's a lot more going on, however the obscure variable names make it all very cryptic.

Comment: i added more comments up for  all basic variables  after.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the above two comments--the code would be much easier to read with [semantic use of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916897/in-terms-of-programming-what-do-semantics-mean). One example below:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("int_no_of_people").value, 10);
```

Would be better declared as:

```
var numOfPeople = parseInt(document.getElementById("int_no_of_people").value, 10);
```

Second to that, the business requirements aren't quite explicit enough for me to understand why there is a second set of inputs, namely:

```
price <input type="text" id="var_cena" value=""><br>
dep <input type="text" id="var_dep" value=""><br>
```

Can you please describe the [business requirements](http://techwhirl.com/writing-software-requirements-specifications/) in as much detail as possible (i.e., what the function should and shouldn't do, and what it's supposed to be used for)?

Comment: I agree in start i didn't think that someone going to see it :) And basically i am so fresh in js that i am still like sponge take all advice to proceed forward with learning.

Comment: As like this idea is that this code calculate basic price and deposit like quote : Deposits and price are fix numbers as same with discount . Idea is that for every 6 people he give one free so deduct 1 price from price and 1 dep from dep  now whats happening as i write  it can calculate up to 50 people i would be glad to make it to calculate as much as possible automatically. for example every 6 input will trigger some kind of i++ and calculator will know that  he need to discount 1 person

Comment: i tried yesterday to add that but whats happen its calculating normal if u ad one by one but if add 12 he give only one discount he need to add 2 . and same if u example again go down to 6 its still adding 1 more . u can see i will add link to my question.

Comment: Does a child count as a person in terms of discount?

Comment: Also, can you please go through an rename all of your variables to something meaningful? It's a pain to sift through the variables and try to keep track of what each variable is used for. Thanks. :)

Comment: Ok :) i will deal that tonight or tomo